# Html.ActionLink in asp.net MVC object value in wrong format

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper, actionlink

I have a html.actionlink that i wish to display a link to a members profile page like this: http://somesite.com/members/{username}

When use the following markup

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(r.MemberName, "profile", new { MemberName = r.MemberName } )%>
```

I get a link that looks like this: http://somesite.com/members?MemberName={username}

What would i need to change in the ActionLink helper to achieve a url like this:

http://somesite.com/members/{username}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming in your routes the username token is {username} like you show, try this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(r.MemberName, "profile", new { username = r.MemberName } )%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the route that maps "/members/{MemberName}" before other routes in the routing table.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for both your responses... 
I did not have my route matching the value name.

Simply ensuring that my route url matched made it work.

Here's my code....

```
//Global.asax
routes.MapRoute(
    "Profile",
    "members/{membername}",
    new { controller = "Members", action = "Profile", memberName = "" }
);

//In the Controller
public ActionResult Profile(string memberName)
{
  return View();
}

//My Action Link
<%= Html.ActionLink(r.MemberName, "profile", new { memberName = r.MemberName })%>
```

Thanks again